# Qt локаль в консольном приложении

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio, locale

Я пишу компилятор на языке `C++` при помощи `Qt`.

Но русский язык на `консоль` не выводится.

Вот код, который я писал:

```
#include <QtCore>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QString s = u8"Привет!";

    qDebug() << s;

    return 0;
}
```

Вот вывод:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И да, я пишу в `Visual Studio 19`

Comment: а в чем проблема?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Как сделать чтобы Unicode выводился? Например, как в ужасном питоне?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015571/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-c

Comment: там нифига не понятно. Альтернатив нет?

Comment: что вам не понятно? Там 10 ответов - какие вам еще нужны альтернативы?